# How do you embed double-quotes an Elixir string?

Tags: string, elixir, double-quotes

I have a sting that has embedded **"**:

```
tx <iq id="wUcdTMYuYoo41" to="2348138248411@" type="set" xmlns="w:profile:picture">
```

how can i present such a string as a value in Elixir?

for example:

```
iex> s= "tx <iq id="wUcdTMYuYoo41" to="2348138248411@" type="set" xmlns="w:profile:picture">"
```

Using ~s and ~S did not help

```
iex(20)> s=~S("tx <iq id="wUcdTMYuYoo41" to="2348138248411@" type="set" xmlns="w:profile:picture">")              
** (SyntaxError) iex:20: keyword argument must be followed by space after: w:

iex(20)> s=~s("tx <iq id="wUcdTMYuYoo41" to="2348138248411@" type="set" xmlns="w:profile:picture">")
** (SyntaxError) iex:20: keyword argument must be followed by space after: w:

iex(20)>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can escape the double quotes:

```
s ="tx <iq id=\"wUcdTMYuYoo41\" to=\"2348138248411@\" type=\"set\" xmlns=\"w:profile:picture\">"
```

There is a [sigil_s](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/sigils.html#strings) to make this more convenient (there is also [sigil_S](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/sigils.html#interpolation-and-escaping-in-sigils) which doesn't interpolate variables):

```
s = ~s(tx <iq id="wUcdTMYuYoo41" to="2348138248411@" type="set" xmlns="w:profile:picture">)
```

Quotes are also escaped when using multi-line strings (heredocs):

```
"""
tx <iq id="wUcdTMYuYoo41" to="2348138248411@" type="set" xmlns="w:profile:picture">
"""
```

Comment: Thanks. When we pull such strings from a File.stream!("path/to/file") do we need to do same? on each line returned?

Comment: Using `File.Stream` will automatically escape the quotes. e.g. `iex(4)> IO.gets ">"; >""" "TEST "" "; "\"\"\" \"TEST \"\" \"\n"`

Comment: Please ~s and ~S did not work see errors reported in edited question above

Comment: You need a space before the `~` - `s = ~s(...)` not `s=~s(...)`

Answer (score 5):

The `~s` or `~S` sigils are the way to go, you just need a space after your equals sign:

```
iex(1)> s = ~s("tx <iq id="wUcdTMYuYoo41" to="2348138248411@" type="set" xmlns="w:profile:picture">")
"\"tx <iq id=\"wUcdTMYuYoo41\" to=\"2348138248411@\" type=\"set\" xmlns=\"w:profile:picture\">\""

iex(2)> s = ~S("tx <iq id="wUcdTMYuYoo41" to="2348138248411@" type="set" xmlns="w:profile:picture">")
"\"tx <iq id=\"wUcdTMYuYoo41\" to=\"2348138248411@\" type=\"set\" xmlns=\"w:profile:picture\">\""
```