# Removing double quotes from a string

Tags: elixir

I read different methods of strings in elixir.

Converting strings into different types e.t.c

Is it possible that we  remove double quotes from a string?

lets suppose we have a string `"inner_join"` and i want to remove the double quotes to make it like this `inner_join`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#replace/4) out. Most programming languages have a `String.replace` method that allows you to replace characters in a string.

In Elixir, it goes like this:

```
String.replace(~s("inner_join"), ~s("), "")
```

If you wanna know how to embed double-quotes in a string, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33185113/5405968).

Comment: its giving the same double quoted string as an output

Comment: @hammadahmed no, it does not. You are fooled by how `iex` inspects the result of the previous function call. Check how `~s("inner_join")` is printed out by `iex`. This makes me think your original strings _had indeed no quotes_ inside them.

Comment: @mudasobwa yes but is it possible to have output with out the quotes.like this `inner_join`?

Comment: To have the output **where**? In your `Logger.log`/`IO.puts`/`IO.inspect` the quotes will not be present anyway. In `iex` it’s output _for your own convenience_. Try `IO.puts "¡Hola!"` in `iex`, and you’ll get it back _without_ quotes. The main question here is: why on the Earth do you need this in the first place.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks.