# How to escape a single backslash in Elixir when encoding to JSON?

Tags: json, elixir, elixir-poison

I have this body for a request, which in Elixir is represented like this:

```
body = %{
  password: "my\Password"
}
```

I use Poison.encode! to convert it to JSON and what it is being sent is this:

```
%HTTPoison.Request{
    body: "{\"sftp_password\":"\myPassword\"}
  }
```

If I try and escape it with a double backslash:

```
body = %{
  password: "my\\Password"
}
```

this is what is being encoded and sent in the request:

```
%HTTPoison.Request{
    body: "{\"sftp_password\":"\my\\\\Password\"}
  }
```

I also tried to convert the string to a `charlist` and it just encodes the code points, not the actual characters.

Is there any way to encode just one backslash, or to put it more generally: how do I pass string literals when encoding with Poison or in Elixir in general?

Comment: `"my\Password" == "myPassword" #⇒ true`. Do you want to escape exactly what? The string containing a slash inside? Then use `"my\\Password"` and whoever would _decode_ it, will get `"my\\Password"` as desired.

Comment: Take a look at sigils https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185095/how-do-you-embed-double-quotes-an-elixir-string

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff I doubt sigils would help here. `"my\\Password"` is pretty much like what they need. The encoded result just _seems_ obscure, but it’s correct.

Comment: Just to rephrase what @AlekseiMatiushkin is saying - there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with what's happening in your example. The final result is an Elixir representation of a string containing the JSON-encoded Elixir data structure. Perhaps if you gave more details as to when you're experiencing problems or what were you expecting to happen instead we could be more helpful.